# editing 3 files

Tags: sql

I have no knowledge when it comes to sql. I have 3 dat files that all use seperate sql files to make changes in the dat files. I wanted to know if its possible to edit all 3 with one single sql file.

Example

```
UPDATE file1
SET PRINT_STATUS='No', ROTYPE='test'

WHERE AA_NUMBER=0000
OR AA_NUMBER=0000
OR AA_NUMBER=0000
OR AA_NUMBER=0000
OR AA_NUMBER=0000

DELETE FROM file2

WHERE ABTYPE='C' AND ABNUMBER='0000'
OR ABNUMBER='0000'
OR ABNUMBER='0000'
OR ABNUMBER='0000'
OR ABNUMBER='0000'

DELETE FROM file3

WHERE ACNUMBER=0000
OR ACNUMBER=0000
OR ACNUMBER=0000
OR ACNUMBER=0000
OR ACNUMBER=0000
```

Sorry if I am not making sense.

Comment: what kind of a system is this on?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Like i said , I simply am helping a friend with a program and noticed that some information could be changed with a simple change in the text. Now i wanted to know if i could avoid using 3 sql files with (all have 1 query) (hope i'm saying that right) in them and simply put them all together. Sorry if im not making any sense again.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  Did you find out anything?  When you mention SQL, I'm thinking of connecting to a database server rather than operating on files.  I was hoping to get some more information so I could familiarize myself with the environment before offering advice.